# How to get data to excel from web that the data is not in a table?

Tags: excel, export-to-excel

My Excel doesn't have edit in import from web option.

(import from web => right click on the folder sign which is the main link)

How can i get the specific value that i added in the screenshot below?

Link: https://www.tefas.gov.tr/FonAnaliz.aspx?FonKod=TCD

Screenshot of the data that i want to get in excel

[image: Screenshot of the data that i want to get in excel]

Thanks from now on...

Answer (score 0):

PQ is capable to extract data which is not in a visible table.

```
let
    Source = Web.BrowserContents("https://www.tefas.gov.tr/FonAnaliz.aspx?FonKod=TCD"),
    #"ExtractedTable" = Html.Table(Source, {{"Column1", ".top-list LI"}, {"Column2", ".top-list SPAN"}}, [RowSelector=".top-list LI"]),
    #"ChangedTypes" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"ExtractedTable",{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}}),
    #"Extracted" = Table.TransformColumns(#"ChangedTypes", {{"Column1", each Text.BeforeDelimiter(_, "  "), type text}})
in
    #"Extracted"
```

[image]

Only retain the number that is highlighted in the OP.

```
let
    Source = Web.BrowserContents("https://www.tefas.gov.tr/FonAnaliz.aspx?FonKod=TCD"),
    #"ExtractedTable" = Html.Table(Source, {{"Column1", ".top-list LI"}, {"Column2", ".top-list SPAN"}}, [RowSelector=".top-list LI"]),
    #"ChangedTypes" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"ExtractedTable",{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}}),
    #"Extracted" = Table.TransformColumns(#"ChangedTypes", {{"Column1", each Text.BeforeDelimiter(_, "  "), type text}}),
    #"FilterRow" = Table.SelectRows(Extracted, each ([Column1] = "Son Fiyat (TL)#(lf)")),
    #"Output" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"FilterRow",{"Column1"})
in
    #"Output"
```

[image]

Comment: Please correct me where i do something wrong because i get error

Steps I Follow:
1- I select Data tab and select from web option.
2- I enter the link, then Navigator opens. A folder which is in name of the link and 2 tables which are document and table 0 
3- I select the Folder (link) then i press Transform Data
4- Then the power query editor opens.
5- On the left side there is Queries tab, which show 1 query with table icon and the link is the name of it.
5- I right click on that then press Advanced Editor
6- Then i paste what you wrote on the first code block of your answer

Comment: 7- I press Done and ı get this error: Expression.Error: The import Html.Table matches no exports. Did you miss a module reference?

8- Then i press Go To Error, It takes me to second phase of the Applied Steps which is Extracted Table step. 

9- When i get there, the error is: Expression.Error: The name 'Html.Table' wasn't recognized.  Make sure it's spelled correctly.

What should i do ? 

Thank you for your time...

Comment: The result of Step 2 is 5 tables on my test. I have uloaded a screenshot. btw, I'm use Excel 365.

Comment: I don't see a way to create or edit Power Queries in Excel for Web. It does look like if you create the query in Excel 365 on the desktop, the query can be refreshed in Excel for Web.